# how to fix Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

So im using an old sdk version which is "Android API 21 Platform" because I'm only trying to make a simple application for my school project, and I want to add google maps to my flutter app which needs for minSdkVersion to be changed to 20
while my build.gradle file looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.untitled"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

so is it possible to stick with this sdk version to fix this problem or do I need to upgrade to the latest sdk version?